# In Ssrs 2019, how does one interpret Subscriptions.InactiveFlags?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2019

In the Ssrs database catalog, how are you supposed to interpret the `InactiveFlags` column of the `Subscriptions` table?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I couldn't find anything really authoritative/complete out there on the 'Net (well, beyond "`InactiveFlags = 0` means the subscription is enabled"). I perused the built-in sprocs/funcs in Ssrs, but except for `DeliveryRemovedInactivateSubscription`, they all just pass through whatever value they're given.

So I went and decompiled the ReportingServicesLibrary.dll (I used "[dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy)") and found the Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.InActiveFlags enum. I've personally experienced "8" and "16" from past work with Ssrs 2012, so everything lines up. It's a bit-mask, defined as follows:

```cs
internal enum InActiveFlags
{
    Active, // 0
    DeliveryProviderRemoved, // 1
    SharedDataSourceRemoved, // 2
    MissingParameterValue = 4,
    InvalidParameterValue = 8,
    UnknownItemParameter = 16,
    MissingExtensionEncryptedSettings = 32,
    CachingNotEnabledOnItem = 64,
    DisabledByUser = 128
}
```

E.g.

```sql
--Find subs with invalid params ('cause someone made a breaking change to the report after the sub was created).
SELECT * FROM Subscriptions WHERE InactiveFlags & 8 != 0;
```